# execution modulo on a large number in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the remainder of one number divided by another. for instance with these numbers:

271011240311350356232122 % 97

When I just want to do that in a sql statement, it works like a charm:

select 271011240311350356232122 % 97;

But when I have that large number in a varchar variable, I can't seem to get the job done.
I can't convert it into a int or even bigint, because it's too large. I can't convert it into a real because you can't use the modulo operator on a real number.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is too big for `bigint` you can use `NUMERIC(38,0)`

```
DECLARE @Num VARCHAR(38) = '271011240311350356232122'
SELECT CAST(@Num AS NUMERIC(38,0)) % 97
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I thought numeric was just a alias for int, but I guess I was confused with oracle (where integer is the same as number(38))